# update php database with data of two

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables where I need to display text in a table corresponding to the users of the users table.

So I did this:

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT t.id, t.id_textos, t.userTitleSite, t.userTextSobre, t.userTextContatos, t.userTextMaisInfos FROM vms_textos t INNER JOIN vms_users u ON (t.id = u.id) LIMIT 1") or print (mysql_error());
while($res_select = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

    $userTitleSite = $res_select["userTitleSite"];
    $userTextSobre = $res_select["userTextSobre"];
    $userTextContatos = $res_select["userTextContatos"];
    $userTextMaisInfos = $res_select["userTextMaisInfos"];
    $id = $res_select["id"];
```

and working. 
Now i need to update this information straight from the INPUTS.. 
but I can not do because my field UPDATE must be wrong because it always resets everything after that grip on SUBMIT. 
This is the code I'm using. 
 Please see what is wrong:

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE vms_textos SET userTitleSite='$userTitleSite', userTextSobre='$userTextSobre', userTextContatos='$userTextContatos', userTextMaisInfos='$userTextMaisInfos' WHERE t.id=u.id");
```

Thanks!

[EDIT]

ALL IMPORTANT CODE:

```
// INCLUDES.PHP

// Starts
ob_start();
session_start();

// Globais
$startaction="";


// Ação
        if(isset($_GET["acao"])){
                $acao=$_GET["acao"];
                $startaction=1;
        }


// Conexão com o banco de dados
$conectar=new DB;
$conectar=$conectar->conectar();



// Metodos de Cadastro
if($startaction == 1){
        if($acao == "cadastrar"){
                $usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
                $nome=$_POST["nome"];
                $sobrenome=$_POST["sobrenome"];
                $telefone=$_POST["telefone"];
                $email=$_POST["email"];
                $senha=$_POST["senha"];

                if(empty($usuario) || empty($nome) || empty($sobrenome) || empty($telefone) || empty($email) || empty($senha)){
                        $msg="Preencha todos os campos!";
                }
                // Todos os campos preenchidos
                else {
                        // Email válido
                        if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                                // Senha inválida
                                if(strlen($senha) < 8){
                                        $msg="As senhas devem conter no mínimo oito caracteres!";
                                }
                                // Senha válida
                                else {
                                        // Executa a classe de cadastro
                                        $conectar=new Cadastro;
                                        echo "<div class=\"flash\">";
                                        $conectar=$conectar->cadastrar($usuario, $nome, $sobrenome, $telefone, $email, $senha);
                                        echo "</div>";
                                }

                        }
                        // Email invalido
                        else{
                                $msg="Digite seu e-mail corretamente!";

                        }

                }


        }
}



// Método de Login
if($startaction == 1){
        if($acao == "logar"){
                // Dados
                $email=addslashes($_POST["email"]);
                $senha=addslashes(sha1($_POST["senha"].""));

                if(empty($email) || empty($senha)){
                        $msg="Preencha todos os campos!";
                } else{
                        if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                                $msg="Digite seu e-mail corretamente!";
                        } else {
                                // Executa a busca pelo usuário
                                $login=new Login;
                                echo "<div class=\"flash\">";
                                $login=$login->logar($email, $senha);
                                echo "</div>";
                        }
                }
        }
}



// Método de Checar usuário
if(isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["senha"])){
        $logado=1;
        $nivel=$_SESSION["nivel"];
}









// LOGIN.PHP -- CLASSE DE LOGIN
class Login {
                public function logar($email, $senha){
                        $buscar=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vms_users WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha' LIMIT 1");
                        if(mysql_num_rows($buscar) == 1){
                                $dados=mysql_fetch_array($buscar);
                                if($dados["status"] == 1){
                                        $_SESSION["email"]=$dados["email"];
                                        $_SESSION["senha"]=$dados["senha"];
                                        $_SESSION["nivel"]=$dados["nivel"];
                                        setcookie("logado",1);
                                        $log=1;
                                } else{
                                        $flash="Usuário bloqueado! Entre em contato conosco!";
                                }
                        }
                        if(isset($log)){
                                $flash="Você foi logado com sucesso!";
                        } else{

                                if(empty($flash)){
                                        $flash="Ops, digite seu e-mail e sua senha corretamente!";
                                }
                        }

                        echo $flash;
                }
        }






// CADASTRO.PHP  -- CLASSE DE CADASTRO
 class Cadastro{
        public function cadastrar($usuario, $nome, $sobrenome, $telefone, $email, $senha){
                // Tratamento das variaveis
                $usuario=ucwords(strtolower($usuario));
                $nome=ucwords(strtolower($nome));
                $sobrenome=ucwords(strtolower($sobrenome));
                $telefone=ucwords(strtolower($telefone));
                $email=ucwords(strtolower($email));
                $senha=sha1($senha."");

                // Inserção no banco de dados
                $validaremail=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vms_users WHERE email='$email' OR usuario='$usuario'");
                $contar=mysql_num_rows($validaremail);
                if($contar == 0){
                        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO vms_users(usuario, nome, sobrenome, telefone, email, senha, nivel, status) VALUES('$usuario','$nome','$sobrenome','$telefone','$email','$senha','1','0')");
                } else{
                        $flash="Desculpe, mas já existe um usuário cadastrado com este e-mail em nosso sistema!";
                }

                if(isset($insert)){
                        // Cadatro ok
                        $flash="Cadastro realizado com sucesso, aguarde nossa aprovação!";

                } else{
                        if(empty($flash)){
                                $flash="Ops, houve um erro em nosso sistema!";
                        }
                }

                // Retorno para o usuário
                echo $flash;
        }
 }
```

Comment: why you used WHERE t.id=u.id without any join?

Comment: too "reset" all with email='$email'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE vms_textos SET t.userTitleSite='$userTitleSite' WHERE t.id='u.id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE vms_textos SET userTitleSite='$userTitleSite' WHERE t.id=u.id");
```

what field do u want to update in db? SET that particular field in mysql_query(). i mentioned here.. try like this if u set all fields then all fields are updated..

Comment: $query=mysql_query("UPDATE vms_textos SET t.userTitleSite='$userTitleSite' WHERE t.id='u.id'");

Comment: *_*
I LOVE YOU!!

10 HOURS MORE TRYING AND NOTHING!!

Comment: where I press to put 1000 his reputation? kkkk

Comment: may i know how many years u have experience in php field? if answer is correct then u can update (this answer useful)

Comment: me too... just 3 weeks ago started php pgming